# Extjs.form.field.Trigger with a help icon

Tags: extjs

Is there a built-in icon and class for making a trigger with a help icon (like there is a class 'x-form-clear-trigger' for a trigger with a delete icon)?

More general: is somewhere in the extjs documentation a list of predefined styles for the trigger field type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Native ExtJS have this four possible trigger class (list you can find in the first comment on triggerCls [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Trigger-cfg-triggerCls)):

```
x-form-clear-trigger     // the X icon
x-form-search-trigger    // the magnifying glass icon
x-form-trigger           // the down arrow (default for combobox) icon
x-form-date-trigger      // the calendar icon (just in case)
```

Native class for help icon does not exists, but you can define your own css class and use it as `triggerCls`

Comment: can you give an example on how to write our desired triggerCls in a right way?